# Can't get an AngularJS template to display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to walk through an Angular tutorial and having trouble with some basics.

I have the following directory structure:

```
index.html
angular.min.js
angular-route.js
app
    views
        customers.html
        orders.html
```

The files in app/views/ folder are templates. In index.html, I have the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="customersApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('customersApp', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'CustomersController',
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/customers.html'
                })
                .when('/orders',
                {
                    controller: 'OrdersController',
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/orders.html'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        });

        app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                { "id": 1, "name": 'Ted', "total": 5.994 },
                { "id": 2, "name": 'Michelle', "total": 2.994 }
            ];
        });

        app.controller('OrdersController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.customerId = 5;
        });        

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In customers.html, I have the following:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomersController">
    Search:
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
    {{ searchText }}


    <h3>Customers: </h3>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:searchText">
            <!-- <td>{{ cust.id }}</td>-->
            <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.total | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Given that I have `<div ng-view></div>` in index.html, I would thing that Angular would correctly route me to the customers.html template, but it displays an empty screen.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why won't my template display?  Am I missing something simple?
2. How do I debug this problem? I've looked in the F12 tools and see no errors under console.  I've stepped through the code and there are no errors.

P.S.  I know the directory structure is not optimal.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, can you create a plunker?  Also, you don't need to declare `<div ng-controller="CustomersController">` in the `customers.html` because you are already assigning a controller in the route config.  Otherwise, you end up with 2 controllers created.

Comment: @DavinTryon Well, crap.  It works on plunker.

Comment: @DavinTryon I replaced the refs to local angular files with the CDNed ones and it works great.  No idea why.

Comment: Bad path to the local file?

Comment: @DavinTryon Possibly but you'd think that the F12 tools would show it.

Comment: You cannot load templates from local files because angular uses ajax to load template files and ajax is not allowed to access local files.

Comment: @KhanhTO I didn't load from local.  I setup Mongoose to host them.